# NiFi Consume kafka sasl_plaintext issue

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

Im trying to configure Oracle cloud streaming kafka from topic with sasl_plaintext security using in nifi. While im gettting issue and stacktrace mentioned below; Kindly have a look and jass configuration also. Kindly anyone help me out from this issue;
And i have configured in bootstrap.conf file also;

I have tried nifi processor itself also; Here is the configuration img;
[image]

kafka version 2.0 and kafka nifi kakfa consumer_processor also consume_kafka_record_2.0 processor also. NiFi-1.9,2

```
java.arg.16=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/opc/nifi-1.9.2/kafka_client_jaas.conf
```

kafka_client_jaas.conf

```
KafkaClient {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
username="aaabbb"
password="cccdddde";
};




2020-10-30 05:41:18,638 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=devtes_grp] Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2020-10-30 05:41:18,691 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=devtes_grp] Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2020-10-30 05:41:18,719 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-1] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@b4bca55 // Another save pending = false
2020-10-30 05:41:18,794 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=devtes_grp] Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2020-10-30 05:41:19,047 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=devtes_grp] Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2020-10-30 05:41:19,450 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=devtes_grp] Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2020-10-30 05:41:20,255 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=devtes_grp] Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2020-10-30 05:41:21,114 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=devtes_grp] Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2020-10-30 05:41:21,920 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=devtes_grp] Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2020-10-30 05:41:22,875 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=devtes_grp] Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2020-10-30 05:41:23,189 INFO [NiFi Web Server-19] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Stopping ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_0[id=7479eb76-0175-1000-bee8-c2013de52f23]
```

Comment: Provide more info: version of Kafka, which Kafka processors are you using

Comment: Yeah updated please check this above versions

Comment: So your mechanism is PLAIN and your protocol is SASL_PLAINTEXT?

Answer (score 1):

I can able to resolve this issue. I added standardsslsecurityservice with default java caerts and password and jks type and changed securityprotocol - SASL, security mechanishm - PLAIN

[image]